# NgTagInput not showing auto-search results

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I am trying to implement [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api#tagsInput) in which I  want to implement auto search for email. for that I write below code. but it not display auto search result

HTML :

```
<tags-input ng-model="compose.receiver"
            add-from-autocomplete-only="true" 
            min-length="1">
    <auto-complete source="loadReceiver($query)" 
                   min-length="0"
                   debounce-delay="0" 
                   max-results-to-show="10" 
                   loadOnEmpty="true">
    </auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.loadReceiver = function(query){
  return AdminInbox.loadReceiver(query);
}
```

Service :

```
angular.module('inboxes').factory('AdminInbox', ['$http','$q',
  function($http,$q) {
    return {
      loadReceiver: function(query) {
        console.log(query);
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var receiver = $http.get('mailreceiver/'+query);
        console.log(receiver);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

and I successfully get response in below format:

```
[{_id: "5579c9a4f3d71f8c2a4f1e3d"  email: "abc@gmail.com"},
{_id: "557f2cd3a571f9a41e4168f2"  email: "xyz@gmail.com"}]
```

Comment: Your JSON seems to be invalid. Are you sure there is no JS error when parsing the result? The properties are seperated with a comma. After having a brief look at ngTagInput I think the response objects should contain a **text** property. `[{"text":"aaaaaa"}, {"text":"bbbbb"}]`

Comment: so does it mean keyName for Text is really necessary? can't I set dynamic key's like email?

Comment: I don't know. Please check the ngTagInput API. There are quiet a bunch of properties

Comment: I checked it first but could not find any suitable solution for my question and that's why I ask this question into SO

Comment: Where did you look?? I think `displayProperty` sounds promising

Comment: I did but still I didn't see search options

Comment: Please provide a working plunker or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Have a valid JSON and set the `display-property` and it works!

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngTagsInput'])
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.source = [{
      _id: "5579c9a4f3d71f8c2a4f1e3d",
      email: "abc@gmail.com"
    }, {
      _id: "557f2cd3a571f9a41e4168f2",
      email: "xyz@gmail.com"
    }];

    $rootScope.compose = {
      receiver: []
    };
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/css/ng-tags-input.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.24/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-tags-input/2.3.0/ng-tags-input.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <tags-input ng-model="compose.receiver" display-property="email" add-from-autocomplete-only="true" min-length="1">
    <auto-complete source="source" min-length="0" debounce-delay="0" max-results-to-show="10" loadOnEmpty="true" displayProperty="email">
    </auto-complete>
  </tags-input>
</div>
```